# Having trouble creating table outputting number of occurences per month

Tags: excel, date, pivot-table

I am trying to create a pivot table that displays the number of projects ongoing per month. I have start and end dates for the project, the project number, and the employee responsible for the project. I would like to delineate the pivot table by month, showing the total number of projects, and then being able to drop that down even further with the projects in that month. I have low experience with pivot tables so I appreciate any help.

Here is a table of the data.

```
+---------+----------+------------+------------+
| Project | Employee | Start Date |  End Date  |
+---------+----------+------------+------------+
| BT 1    | Jack     | 9/16/2019  | 12/13/2019 |
| BT 2    | Jack     | 9/22/2019  | 12/20/2019 |
| BT 3    | Jack     | 9/23/2019  | 12/20/2019 |
| BT 4    | Jack     | 9/29/2019  | 12/20/2019 |
| BT 5    | Jack     | 9/23/2019  | 1/9/2020   |
| BT 6    | Jack     | 9/16/2019  | 1/10/2020  |
| BT 7    | Jane     | 9/30/2019  | 12/13/2019 |
| BT 8    | Jack     | 10/3/2019  | 1/24/2020  |
| BT 9    | Jane     | 10/7/2019  | 1/17/2020  |
| BT 10   | Jane     | 11/4/2019  | 3/13/2020  |
| BT 11   | Jim      | 11/12/2019 | 3/20/2020  |
| BT 12   | Jim      | 12/1/2019  | 2/20/2020  |
| BT 13   | Jane     | 12/2/2019  | 3/4/2020   |
| BT 14   | Jim      | 12/2/2019  | 3/27/2020  |
| BT 15   | Jim      | 12/9/2019  | 4/3/2020   |
| BT 16   | Jack     | 1/5/2020   | 2/27/2020  |
| BT 17   | Jim      | 12/16/2019 | 4/17/2020  |
| BT 18   | Jack     | 1/2/2020   | 3/25/2020  |
| BT 19   | Jack     | 1/12/2020  | 3/27/2020  |
| BT 20   | Jack     | 12/15/2019 | 4/2/2020   |
| BT 21   | Jack     | 1/6/2020   | 4/10/2020  |
| BT 22   | Jack     | 1/6/2020   | 4/10/2020  |
| BT 23   | Jack     | 1/13/2020  | 4/10/2020  |
| BT 24   | Jack     | 1/13/2020  | 4/24/2020  |
| BT 25   | Shane    | 1/19/2020  | 3/20/2020  |
| BT 26   | Jack     | 2/3/2020   | 5/8/2020   |
| BT 27   | Jack     | 2/24/2020  | 5/15/2020  |
| BT 28   | Jack     | 2/17/2020  | 5/22/2020  |
| BT 29   | Jack     | 4/13/2020  | 5/22/2020  |
| BT 30   | Jack     | 2/9/2020   | 5/29/2020  |
| BT 31   | Jack     | 2/17/2020  | 5/29/2020  |
| BT 32   | Jack     | 4/19/2020  | 5/29/2020  |
| BT 33   | Jack     | 3/16/2020  | 6/5/2020   |
| BT 34   | Jack     | 3/1/2020   | 6/18/2020  |
| BT 35   | Jack     | 4/13/2020  | 7/10/2020  |
| BT 36   | Jack     | 4/13/2020  | 7/10/2020  |
| BT 37   | Jack     | 6/8/2020   | 7/24/2020  |
| BT 38   | Jack     | 3/30/2020  | 7/31/2020  |
| BT 39   | Jack     | 4/13/2020  | 8/7/2020   |
| BT 40   | Jack     | 4/20/2020  | 8/7/2020   |
| BT 41   | Jack     | 5/11/2020  | 8/7/2020   |
| BT 42   | Jack     | 7/5/2020   | 9/30/2020  |
| BT 43   | Jack     | 7/12/2020  | 9/30/2020  |
| BT 44   | Jack     | 6/8/2020   | 10/2/2020  |
| BT 45   | Jack     | 7/13/2020  | 10/2/2020  |
| BT 46   | Jack     | 7/6/2020   | 10/9/2020  |
| BT 47   | Jack     | 6/14/2020  | 10/22/2020 |
| BT 48   | Jack     | 7/6/2020   | 10/23/2020 |
| BT 49   | Jack     | 8/3/2020   | 10/30/2020 |
| BT 50   | Jack     | 7/13/2020  | 11/13/2020 |
| BT 51   | Jack     | 7/27/2020  | 11/13/2020 |
| BT 52   | Jack     | 9/14/2020  | 12/11/2020 |
| BT 53   | Jack     | 11/2/2020  | 2/19/2021  |
+---------+----------+------------+------------+
```

Thanks.

Comment: to use a pivot table like that you would need a line per month for each project.  It will not extrapolate from a start and end date.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59313065/edit) your post and paste the table data

Comment: Sorry, I have added the table.